# Segmentation fault: 1902 vfscanf.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

The program stops with segmentation fault at `scanf()` function.

```
int main() {
  int x = 0;
  printf("$ ");
  scanf("%i", x);

  return 0;
}
```

And GDB returns following error:

```bash
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff71f6794 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffe608, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1902
1902    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

I tried searching the internet for vfscanf.c but haven't found much helpful information.

The program was compiled with g++, which is (same as GDB) newly updated.

Comment: `scanf("%i", &x);` you need to pass a reference for X, not the value

Comment: That's just `gdb` telling you it can't show you the source code of the **exact** location where the segfault happened (because you don't have source of the standard libraries on your system). It has nothing to do with the reason for the segfault, which is what @cleblanc said.

Comment: You don't need to spend time to search for C standard library function source code. You can assume that the error is on your side. The function name is a good hint from debugger which function was called erronously.

Comment: While at it, if these are your first tries, I anticipate a lot of pain: 1.) `scanf()` most of the time [isn't the way to read user input](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). 2.) "*I compile this program with g++*" <- C and C++ are **different** languages, so this is a *very bad idea*

Comment: @Felix "*Very bad idea (tm)*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%i", &x);
//          ^ THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT
```

---

gcc even tells you about this:

```
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6:9: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", x);
         ^
```

The `vfscanf.c: No such file or directory` is just gdb complaining that it can't find the source code for `scanf`.

Comment: my vote would be to make warnings fatal by default. This would help new programmers enormously. Once they got experienced enough to understand which warning to ignore they would also be experienced enough to turn off the warning=fatal option

Comment: If you want to do this to everyone, `echo 'alias gcc="gcc -Werror"' >> /etc/bash.bashrc`.  If you want to do it to yourself, `echo 'alias gcc="gcc -Werror"' >> ~/.bashrc`